# how to upload images and gifs with c#

Tags: c#, angularjs, photo-upload

I have a project. It's server side is built with c# and the client side works with angular. I need to allow the user to upload gifs from his/her mobile.

What is the best practice to handle the server side & the client side?

Of course, I need to assure that the uploaded file is an image/animated gif (is there a difference between the two, as far as to the server's concern?) and to compress the file. The quality loss due to the compression is not a concern, yet I would like to avoid it as much as possible).

Comment: You have many options.  What were YOU thinking?  Have you tried anything?  Some code attempts perhaps?  What pattern/framework (MVC, ASP.NET... etc.) are you using on the c# server side?  Is you client side Typescript or JavaScript?  Let's jump start this question...

Comment: I have done nothing but searching for an option, yet I couldn't find one that fits my needs. On my server side I'm following MVC and using C#. My client side is Javascript, forgot to mention that. My #1 concern is the compression - I need to compress the image on the client side so not to put a lot of work on the server. The images will be taken on mobiles (ios & android).

Comment: Which do you not know?  How to upload with angularjs and MVC, and/or how to compress on the client side (keep in mind GIFs are already compressed, and the mobile camera might take in a different format)?